# id for query in DB used in two parts

Tags: node.js, express, mariadb

I am using MariaDB database and performing a query through NodeJs and express. In the query I must pass an id, but this must go in two parts of the query (?), for further illustration this is the code:

```
routes.get('/ajustarOTCP/:id', (req, res)=>{
req.getConnection((err, connection)=>{
    if(err) return res.send(err);
    connection.query(`
    SELECT * FROM developmentrequest
    INNER JOIN potentialclients ON potentialclients.id_potentialclients = developmentrequest.id_potentialclients
    INNER JOIN users ON potentialclients.id_user = users.id
    INNER JOIN products ON products.id_productdevelopment = developmentrequest.id_developmentrequest
    WHERE users.id =?
    UNION
    SELECT * FROM developmentrequest
    INNER JOIN clients ON clients.id_clients = developmentrequest.id_clients
    INNER JOIN users ON clients.id_user = users.id
    INNER JOIN products ON products.id_productdevelopment = developmentrequest.id_developmentrequest
    WHERE users.id =?`, [req.params.id], (err, rows)=>{
        if(err) return res.send(err);
        res.json(rows);
    });
})
})
```

I have not been able to know how to pass the id so that it is taken in both queries.

Who could help me?

Comment: I've not used node.js so I'm not going to put this as an answer, but I believe you can pass in the same value twice to fill both parameters. `[req.params.id, req.params.id]` (as one option).

Comment: I'd consider moving the `potentialclients` into the `clients` database and consolidating `developmentrequest.id_potentialclients` and `developmentrequest.id_clients` to make writing (and executing) this query significantly easier and probably many other queries you come up with. It would also make the `potentialclient` -> `client` transition a simple change of a flag in that table.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help [JNevill](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2221001/jnevill), I had tried several things and the truth was that I couldn't find the solution. very thankful

Comment: thanks for your advice [danblack](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10195153/danblack), I'll take it into consideration